# Mongo query in json format to select one column only

Tags: mongodb

I want to write a mongo query in json format to select data from a single column only.

Sample query in json format looks like

````
    "collection": "<collection_name>",
    "query": {
        "mobile" : { "$in": [ "<mobile_number>" ]  }
    }
}```
````

Comment: In general, you use _projection_ to select the columns / fields you want to display or use.

Comment: Explain a sample output and input document

Comment: Hi @prasad_ I tried using projection but not able to accomplish the task.

Comment: @Gibbs there can be multiple fields in mongo document like id, firstName, lastName. Now I want to fetch only firstName of users from documents.

Comment: @prasad_ solution will work for you